# Поиск по всему массиву, и вывод значения

Tags: php, массивы

подскажите, как лучше всего выполнить поиск по данному массиву. Поиск значения "name". Если "name" совпадает, то выводить id

```html
    "array": {
        "1027": {
            "id": 1, 
            "name": "Value1", 
        },
        "1027": {
            "id": 2, 
            "name": "Value2", 
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение:

```
function find($arr, $name)
{
    $found = [];
    foreach($arr as $elem)
    {
        if($elem["name"] == $name)
            $found[] = $elem["id"];
    }
    return $found;
}
```

Использование:

```
$arr = [
    "1027" => [
        "id" => 1,
        "name" => "Value1",
    ],
    "1028" => [
        "id" => 2,
        "name" => "Value2",
    ],
    "1029" => [
        "id" => 3,
        "name" => "Value1",
    ]   
];

var_dump(find($arr, 'Value1')); // array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(3) }
var_dump(find($arr, 'sss'));    // array(0) { }
```

Comment: Ваша функция вернет только первый соответствующий элемент и на этом закончится.

Comment: @Эникейщик по-другому понял вопрос с первого раза, поправил, теперь работает как надо.

Comment: @АртемПоликарпов разве вы не видите, что в первом посту не массив, а json-строка: `"1027": {...}`? Откуда появилась такая запись: `"1027" => [...]`?

Comment: @Эдуард вопрос звучит: "как лучше всего выполнить поиск по данному массиву", а не "как из данного json'a ...". Отсюда я и сделал вывод, что следует работать именно с массивом, а декодирование json'a - отдельная тема, которая в вопросе никак не всплывает.

Comment: @Эдуард, если быть честным, в посте нет никакого json..

Answer (score 1):

Если это действительно массив, то можно воспользоваться одной из php-функций для работы с массивами, и проверять по условию значение текущего элемента:

```
$arr = [
    "1027" => [
        "id" => 1,
        "name" => "Value1",
    ],
    "1028" => [
        "id" => 2,
        "name" => "Value2",
    ],
    "1029" => [
        "id" => 3,
        "name" => "Value1",
    ]   
];

$need = 'Value1';

array_walk($arr, function($it)use($need){
    $need != $it['name'] ?: print $it['id'] . '<br>';
});
```

Результат:

```
1
3
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
$data_array = array("1027" => array ( "id" => "1", "name" => "Value1"),
"1028" => array ( "id" => "2", "name" => "Value2")
);

$name = "Value1";

foreach($data_array as $DA){ //Проходим цыклом по елементам масива
    if($DA[name] == $name){ // Если запись name в масиве соответствует переменной $name то выводим айди записи
        echo $DA[id];
    }
}
```

Comment: Для сравнения строк в пхп лучше использовать ``===``. Или ``strcmp(s1, s2)``.

Comment: `PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant` - несмотря на то, что вы отключили этот уровень в error_reporting, они всё ещё генерируют бесполезные логи...